On a ringed world would most ring fragments fall from the same direction?
I want to write a story set on a ringed world. I understand that small meteorite impacts and showers would most likely be more common than here on earth. I am wondering if meteorites and cosmic dust escaping from the ring and being pulled into the planets atmosphere would usually come from the direction of the rings orbit/the ring itself or if the chaotic nature of a planetary ring makes it impossible to predict the general direction of meteor showers and meteorite impacts.
Furthermore if the direction was mostly predictable what parts of the underlying planet would get bombarded with meteorites the most? Or would that be almost be impossible to know planetside?

Some interesting links to add to your research: this, this, this. Also, note that "chaotic" doesn't mean, "they're going every which way." It means that ring particles are colliding while orbiting at, on average, the same speed in the same direction. Retrograde impact debris in a prograde ring wouldn't be impossible, but it would be rare on the whole.

One more thing, for future reference, Stack Exchange allows one question per post. You're asking two. To address the second, rings have thickness. So the band of space on the planet equal in width and placement as the ring would have the highest statistical chance of impact. That statistical chance lowers as you approach the poles. It's never zero anywhere in space. This is good for you as it adds interest to the story. Impacts are occasional in Canada on a fictional Earth with equatorial rings and "common" (by comparison) in Indonesia.

Here is an image of the equatorial ridge of Iapetus. It is closely aligned with the actual equator, which makes it tempting to conclude that it was formed from falling elements of a now vanished ring system. The cratering shows it to be a very old feature, which casts some doubt on this theory.
Let us suppose this is a collapsed ring. The objects in the ring seem to have kept to the plane of the ring until they hit the moon. They probably had an orbit that grazed the moon before they finally hit, so they would have been travelling almost parallel to the surface.

That's one of the coolest pictures I've ever seen.

Likely meaning "the actual equator".

@FrançoisJurain Yes. It is the plane perpendicular to Iapetus' rotational axis. This would not necessarily be in the same plane as a ring, if the ring was due to some sub-moon that had broken up. But it might be if Iapetus and the ring condensed from a common rotating cloud of debris. This is still being argued about.

So that's where the actual equator enters the actual equation.

The fragments do not fall, as the rings usually are not rotating much, relative to the body they rotate around. There orbit is just good enough- and if they touch gas - and thus decelerate, they enter a planet rotating into them. Thus most of the particles "enter" streaking with planetary rotation speed + x from west to east on the planet.
If the ring rotates with the planet at exactly the orbital rotation speed of the planet aka looks stationary from the surface, the fragments do not enter regularly at all, but are perceived to fall down at pretty much no angle.

Rings orbit at different speeds depending on their distance from the planet. Saturn's ring segments all have different velocities. Theoretically, if a ring segment is within the geostationary orbital ring it could do as you're suggesting, but I have my doubts that a ring (vs. a singular object like a satellite) would be stable at at that distance. But I guess it would depend on how much mass was involved and whether or not there were any other rings, which would cause gravimetric stress.
